# Sublime Text / subl: Open file in specific group from command line

Tags: command-line, terminal, sublimetext3

I want to open a file from command-line (using `subl` or other means) in Sublime Text, but it always opens in currently active group.

How do I open it in specific group?

I see no option in subl for it and running command like `focusGroup 0` but that too doesn't work.

Use case: I use ST with TerminalView plugin, so first group has all files to edit and second group has bash terminal open. Idea is to open a file in first group through command line in terminal (second group). As of now the file opens in second group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, we need to find what the correct command is to focus the first group. In ST, from the View menu, select Show Console, and then enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, followed by focusing group 1 from the menu: View -> Focus Group -> Group 1. We will see the following in the console:

> command: focus_group { "group": 0 }

Now, to run this command from the command line:

```
subl --command "focus_group { \"group\": 0 }"
```

Then, to open the file:

```
subl /path/to/file
```

This can be shortened to:

```
subl --command "focus_group { \"group\": 0 }" && subl /path/to/file
```

But trying to shorten it to one `subl` invocation will open the file before running the command, meaning it will open in group 2, then switch focus to group 1.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: "select Show Console, and then enter sublime.log_commands(True)" helped me to solve a different automation problem too.